# How to find the greatest number of hits on a resource in any 3 minute interval?

Tags: algorithm

If given an unsorted list like so:

```
[
[100, "/resource1"],
[99, "/resource2"],
[1500, "/resource2"]
...
]
```

Where the first number is a timestamp in seconds since the start of the day and the second element is a resource access time, is there a way to find the resource with the most hits in any 3 minute interval that is more efficient than sorting by timestamp and then keeping track of a running window for each resource?

For example, If one performs a sort by timestamp, then one can make a second pass through the sorted data that will easily calculate the most visited resource with a running list of timestamps for each resource. This, however, is not possible if the data is not sorted first. Is there a way to perform both operations at the same time, sort and keep track of the most visited resource? I'm looking for the most efficient algorithm to find this value.

Comment: How many resources are there?

Comment: An unspecified number. I'm looking for an algorithm that has O(n) runtime.

Comment: I made some edits to make the question more clear.

Comment: There are 480 three-minute intervals in a day. So you could create a list of 480 elements, where each element is a list of resources in that three-minute interval. Creating the list of lists can be done with a single pass through the input. Then you need to go through each three-minute list to find the resource with the most hits. I'm not convinced that that's any faster than just sorting and scanning the input list.

Comment: Any 3 minute interval means relative to a particular timestamp.

Comment: How are your 3 minute intervals defined? Are they specific intervals like the first 3 minutes of the day, then the minutes 4 to 6 inclusive, minutes 7 to 9 inclusive, etc.? Or can the 3 minutes interval begin at any second/milisecond and end 3 minutes later?

Comment: Second one. Any 3 minute interval is any second/milisecond and ends 3 minutes later. So, for example, 3,4,5 would be in one 3 minute interval, while 3,500 would not.